# Why does blender use angle based UV mapping as default instead of conformal?

Tags: uv

Why does blender like to default to angle based UV mapping instead of conformal? when conformal makes neat good looking UV islands with low effort that look stellar, and angle based turns it into a complete mess filled with overlap? Is there a reason to or even actual way to use angle based at all? Or am i just being an idiot?